# Create a CGRect from a matrix_float4x4 Swift

Tags: swift, arkit, coreml

I'm currently working on a project embedding `CoreML, Vision and ARKit`.

For now I can detect and classify object with Vision/CoreML.
But now I want to go further and track the object just found.

So I'm using ARKit for having a sceneView, and I use ARKit hit test, which gives an array of `ARHitTestResult`

If the array of hit tests, is not nil, and take the first one

```
if let closestResult = arHitTestResults.first {....}
```

The closest result, contains two matrices: worldTransform, and localTransform which are `matrix_float4x4` type.

And I would like to "transform" the matrix into a CGRect.
Is there any way to do so ?
I've been looking but didn't find anything.

Comment: A transform matrix represents a translation (position), rotation (orientation), and scale. I’m not sure how you expect any of those (or some combination) to meaningfully constitute a rect.

Comment: i guess you want to create marker in AR. why not create SCNPlane or SCNBox in world transform you get.

Comment: @rickster Hello, thank you for your answer.
I would like to calculate, the position (x,y) and the size (height, width) from the object detected with CoreML.
And then, launch a track request for this object.

Comment: @AlokSubedi I already have the marker above the object detected. I created a SCNNode for it !